# CSS: Change child on parent hover (only single child)

Tags: css

I can change child on parent hover like this:

.parent:hover .child{ ... }

Problem is, that this will change all childs in document.

(I'm using parent 10x on the page => it will change childs in all these parent)

Is there a CSS way, how to change only child of the parent, that I'm currently hovering over?

Example:

```
<div class="parent">
   <p class="child"></p>
</div>

<div class="parent">
   <p class="child"></p>
</div>

<div class="parent">
   <p class="child"></p>
</div>
```

If I hover over first .parent, I want change on its .child. But my mentioned solution will affect all childs.

Comment: that shouldn't change all the childs.

Comment: see: https://jsfiddle.net/jug32e5L/ something else must be going on.

Comment: I'm in "Chrome - Version 62.0.3202.89 (Official Build) (64-bit)" and it does. And that's why I'm asking. Because it's unexpected behaviour for me and I'm confused about it.

Comment: @Daniel A. White:  Cursor is not visible in my screenshot, but I'm hover over number 3. And this is the result:  https://i.imgur.com/rSZ3yNZ.png

Comment: make a fiddle please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll want to directly select the child using the ">" or the "adjacent sibling combinator"

```css
.parent:hover > .child{
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
   <p class="child">child one</p>
</div>

<div class="parent">
   <p class="child">child two</p>
</div>

<div class="parent">
   <p class="child">child three</p>
</div>
```

Comment: you don't need > to get the desired effect, while that is useful there's clearly something weird going on in his code. .parent:hover .child is fine, only the parent being hovered should react